# Unable to call my observer using Factory

Tags: magento2

Can someone tell the right method of calling the objectManager's create() in Observer

**Vendor\Module\Observer\SyncObserver.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SyncObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
//protected $_queue;

/**
 * @var \Vendor\Module\Model\QueueFactory
 */
protected $syncQueueFactory;

/**
 * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
 */
protected $logger;

function __construct(
    \Vendor\Module\Model\QueueFactory $syncQueueFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
)
{
    $this->syncQueueFactory = $syncQueueFactory;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    //$this->_queue = $this->syncQueueFactory->create();
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    echo 'Sync obssrexe';die;
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $this->syncQueueFactory->productUpdate($observer);
}
}
```

Im calling the productUpdate() from Model in the observer

**Vendor\Module\Model\QueueFactory.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class QueueFactory extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    protected $logger;
    protected $_queue;
    protected $syncQueueFactory;

 public function __construct(
  //If i give this i get circular dependency error 

   \Vendor\Module\Model\QueueFactory $syncQueueFactory,
    array $data = []
     ) {
    $this->syncQueueFactory = $syncQueueFactory;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->_queue = $this->syncQueueFactory->create();
      ....
    );
  }
```

How to use syncQueueFactory in my code

Comment: have you created events.xml file under etc/frontend/?

Comment: Yes Abdul, <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="catalog_product_save_after_handler" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SyncObserver"/>
    </event>, events is in etc

Comment: have you run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy?

Comment: i still get error as mentioned, i dont think running that cmd is of use as of now